# Parameterized query not working with PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

i have table name "pages" with "id,title,slug" columns,I am working on core php and trying to use "parameterized update query",whenever i execute my query then its giving me following error

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Here is my code,Where i am wrong ?

```
$sql = "UPDATE pages SET title=? WHERE slug=? AND id=?";
$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param($title,$slug,$headingid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Aside from the SQL syntax issues you are using the PHP functions incorrectly. Have you look at a tutorial on this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While binding a param you should defined what type of is it, like in your case as I guess, title is `string`, slug is `string` and id is `integer`

```
$sql = "UPDATE pages SET title=? WHERE slug=? AND id=?";
$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $title,$slug,$headingid);
$stmt->execute();
```